# How to represent distance to a nonempty, closed, convex set via the support function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

While reading [An easy path to convex analysis and applications](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-031-02406-1) [[PDF]](https://people.scs.carleton.ca/%7Ebertossi/dmbi/material/Convex%20Analysis.pdf), I encountered the following:

> **Exercise 2.33** Let $$d(x;\Omega) = \inf_{\omega \in \Omega} \| x - \omega \|$$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is  a nonempty, closed, convex set. Prove that $$d(x;\Omega) = \sup_{\|v\|\leq 1} \left\{ \langle x, v \rangle - \sigma_\Omega(v) \right\} $$ where $\sigma_\Omega(v) = \sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega} \langle v, \omega \rangle$ is the support function of $\Omega$.

---

I write down

$$ \sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}\{ \langle x, v \rangle - \sigma_\Omega(v)\}  =  \sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}\{\inf_{\omega\in\Omega} \langle x, v \rangle - \langle v, \omega \rangle\} $$

I think if the $\sup$ and $\inf$ switch, it will be obvious, but I can't go further. Any hints on how can I prove this?

Moreover, how can I calculate the subdifferential $\partial d(\bar{x};\Omega) $ at every $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Sorry for my poor typing.. The link is :https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://people.scs.carleton.ca/~bertossi/dmbi/material/Convex%2520Analysis.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjji5_TlNH-AhUQRN4KHdUoD1MQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2i0z9NAS5xvJkIbUnMDwls ,and it's on Page 94, exercise 2.33. I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Note that $\langle x, av \rangle - \sigma_\Omega(av) = a(\langle x, v \rangle - \sigma_\Omega(v))$, So the supremum occurs when $v = 1$. But then $\langle y, v\rangle$ is the distance from $y$ to the line of $v$. And $\sigma_\Omega(v)$ is the furthest distance of any point of $\Omega$ from the line of $v$. If the same point $w$ of $\Omega$ that minimizes the distance to $x$ turns out to also maximize the distance from $v$, then the result would imply that $v$ is perpendicular to the line through $x$ and $w$.  I.e., try to show that the max $v$ satisfies $\langle x-w, v\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Sorry for the late reply, but I think I still can't understand your idea and how to do it... Especially the "If the same point $w$ of $\Omega$ that minimizes the distance to $x$ turns out to also maximize the distance from $v$, then the result would imply that $v$ is perpendicular to the line through $x$ and $w$ ". Why would I want that?

Comment: Because $\Omega$ is closed and convex, there is a unique point $w\in \Omega$ such that $d(x; \Omega) = d(x, w)$. Because the unit ball is closed and convex, there will also be a unique $v$ for the supremum. If $L_v$ is the line through the origin and $v$, and $\hat w$ is the point of $\Omega$ furthest from $L_v$, the claim you are to prove says that $d(x,w) + d(\hat w; L_v) = d(x, L_v)$. Distances between points on a line add like this, which suggests that the maximizing $v$ occurs when $w = \hat w$. Which would mean that $v \perp x-w$.

Comment: So if you solve the equation $\langle x + t(w -x), w-x\rangle = 0$, for $t$, and label $v' = x+t(w-x)$, then this would mean the maximizing $v$ is $\frac{v'}{\}v'\|}$. So you now have a formula for $v$. And what you need to show is that $w$ is indeed the farthest point from $L_v$ in $\Omega$ for this $v$.